# can not parse macro line in Imacros

Tags: javascript, imacros

I am just  new in iMacros this is my first macros. anybody can help out.... its getting an error macro can not parse

```
Error -1100: Can not parse macro line: for(i=1,i<11;i++){
```

Here is the code

```
VERSION BUILD=10022823
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
URL GOTO=http://www.justdial.com/Mumbai/Furniture-Dealers-%3Cnear%3E-jetpur-rajkot/ct-10219686/page-8
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO

for(i=1,i<11;i++){
iimSet("i",i);
var k = 12
k=k+({{i}}*4)
iimPlay(ext);
}

var ext
ext = "CODE:";
ext += "TAG POS={{i}} TYPE=H4 ATTR=CLASS:store-name EXTRACT=TXT";
ext += "TAG POS={{i}} TYPE=P ATTR=CLASS:contact-info EXTRACT=TXT";
ext += "TAG POS={{k}} TYPE=A ATTR=HREF:javascript:void(0); EXTRACT=TXT";
ext += "SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=Extract_{{!NOW:ddmmyy_hhnnss}}.csv";
```

Comment: This code will never work because you combined the syntax of 'iMacros' macros with that of the Scripting Interface in it.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you would get your expected result with this code. Several things had to be changed on your code. Added and option to set your file name at the initial of the code run. Also trimmed the white spaces from the output strings.

I would be very happy if it helps you.

```
iimPlayCode('PROMPT "PLEASE ENTER THE FOLDER NAME FOR OUTPUT FILE" !VAR1'+'\n'+ 'ADD !EXTRACT {{!VAR1}}');
var foldarname = iimGetExtract(1).replace(" ","<SP>");


var trim = 'EVAL("\\\"{{!EXTRACT}}\\\".replace(\\\"#EANF#\\\", \\\"\\\").replace(\\\"more..\\\", \\\"\\\").replace(/^\\\\s*|\\\\s*$/g, \\\"\\\").replace(/\\\\t/g, \\\"\\\").replace(/[\\\\r\\\\n]/g, \\\"\\\");")'+'\n';
trim += 'SET !EXTRACT NULL'+'\n';


var header = "VERSION BUILD=10022823"+'\n';
header += "TAB T=1"+'\n';
header += "SET !TIMEOUT 200"+'\n';
header += "SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0"+'\n';
header += "TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS"+'\n';
header += "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES"+'\n';
header += "SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO"+'\n';

var url = "URL GOTO=http://www.justdial.com/Mumbai/Furniture-Dealers-%3Cnear%3E-jetpur-rajkot/ct-10219686/page-8"+'\n';


var ext = "TAG POS={{i}} TYPE=H4 ATTR=CLASS:store-name EXTRACT=TXT"+'\n';
ext += "SET StoreName "+ trim;
ext += "TAG POS={{i}} TYPE=P ATTR=CLASS:contact-info EXTRACT=TXT"+'\n';
ext += "SET ContactInfo "+ trim;
ext += "TAG POS={{k}} TYPE=A ATTR=HREF:javascript:void(0); EXTRACT=TXT"+'\n';
ext += "SET Address "+ trim;
ext += "ADD !EXTRACT {{StoreName}}"+'\n';
ext += "ADD !EXTRACT {{ContactInfo}}"+'\n';
ext += "ADD !EXTRACT {{Address}}"+'\n';
ext += "SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE={{FOLDER}}.csv"+'\n';
iimPlayCode(header+url)

for(i=1;i<11;i++){

    var k = 12
    k=k+(i*4)
    iimSet("i",i);
    iimSet("k",k);
    iimSet("FOLDER", foldarname);
    iimPlayCode(header+ext);
}
```

**Note:** Don't forget to save this code as JavaScript (.js) file...

Answer (score 0):

thanks mr. Rafayet Ullah for your valuable time for me

i tried this code with javascript.js but its give me an error.

here is the code

```
iimPlayCode('PROMPT "C:\Users\lalit patel\Documents\iMacros\Downloads\" !VAR1'+'\n'+ 'ADD !EXTRACT {{!VAR1}}');
var foldarname = iimGetExtract(1).replace(" ","<SP>");


var trim = 'EVAL("\\\"{{!EXTRACT}}\\\".replace(\\\"#EANF#\\\", \\\"\\\").replace(\\\"more..\\\", \\\"\\\").replace(/^\\\\s*|\\\\s*$/g, \\\"\\\").replace(/\\\\t/g, \\\"\\\").replace(/[\\\\r\\\\n]/g, \\\"\\\");")'+'\n';
trim += 'SET !EXTRACT NULL'+'\n';


var header = "VERSION BUILD=10022823"+'\n';
header += "TAB T=1"+'\n';
header += "SET !TIMEOUT 200"+'\n';
header += "SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0"+'\n';
header += "TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS"+'\n';
header += "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES"+'\n';
header += "SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO"+'\n';

var url = "URL GOTO=http://www.justdial.com/Mumbai/Furniture-Dealers-%3Cnear%3E-jetpur-rajkot/ct-10219686/page-8"+'\n';


var ext = "TAG POS={{i}} TYPE=H4 ATTR=CLASS:store-name EXTRACT=TXT"+'\n';
ext += "SET StoreName "+ trim;
ext += "TAG POS={{i}} TYPE=P ATTR=CLASS:contact-info EXTRACT=TXT"+'\n';
ext += "SET ContactInfo "+ trim;
ext += "TAG POS={{k}} TYPE=A ATTR=HREF:javascript:void(0);     EXTRACT=TXT"+'\n';
ext += "SET Address "+ trim;
ext += "ADD !EXTRACT {{StoreName}}"+'\n';
ext += "ADD !EXTRACT {{ContactInfo}}"+'\n';
ext += "ADD !EXTRACT {{Address}}"+'\n';
ext += "SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE={{FOLDER}}.csv"+'\n';
iimPlayCode(header+url)

for(i=1;i<11;i++){

var k = 12
k=k+(i*4)
iimSet("i",i);
iimSet("k",k);
iimSet("FOLDER", foldarname);
iimPlayCode(header+ext);
}
```

Error -1100: Can not parse macro line: iimPlayCode('PROMPT "C:\Users\lalit patel\Documents\iMacros\Downloads\" !VAR1'+'\n'+ 'ADD !EXTRACT {{!VAR1}}');